# Debian Bullseye install error for postgresql-client-15 (Depends: libreadline7 (>= 6.0) but it is not installable)

Tags: debian, postgresql

I'm inside a docker container that uses the Ruby 3.2.2 Debian 11 bullseye image as a base image (see https://github.com/docker-library/ruby/blob/ed1be47a38a7a24a0aa03c450549afcb592f02a8/3.2/bullseye/Dockerfile)

I want to install only the `postgres-client-15` package using these commands:

```
FROM ruby:3.2.2-bullseye

# ...

RUN curl https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | gpg --dearmor | tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/apt.postgresql.org.gpg >/dev/null
RUN echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ buster-pgdg main 15" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/postgresql.list

#...

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates \
    && apt-key adv --no-tty --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 561F9B9CAC40B2F7 \
    && echo deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger bullseye main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
      autoconf \
      build-essential \
      cron \
      curl \
      ghostscript \
      git \
      less \
      libjemalloc2 \
      libpq-dev \
      libreadline-dev \
      libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 \
      libssl-dev \
      nginx libnginx-mod-http-passenger \
      nodejs \
      postgresql-client-15 \
      redis-server \
      vim \
      xfonts-base \
      xfonts-75dpi \
      xmlsec1 \
      yarn \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

It fails with this error message

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql-client-15 : Depends: libreadline7 (>= 6.0) but it is not installable
```

When I run the commands by hand I can see afterwards, that the package `libreadline8` is installed:

```
root@42da1438f1d6:/# dpkg -l | grep libread
ii  libreadline-dev:amd64              8.1-1                          amd64        GNU readline and history libraries, development files
ii  libreadline8:amd64                 8.1-1                          amd64        GNU readline and history libraries, run-time libraries
```

It seems like postgresql-client-15 depends on `libreadline7` but this package is somehow not available in Debian 11 Bullseye. Any idea how to solve this?

I wouldn't mind upgrading the Docker image itself, but Debian Bookworm throws a similar error (along with other errors, because some packages are not yet available for Bookworm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the use of the Buster PostgreSQL repository; the `postgresql-client-15` package available there uses Buster dependencies, including `libreadline7`.

Since you’re willing to upgrade to Bookworm, you might as well use [the `postgresql-client-15` package shipped in Debian](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/postgresql-client-15), without using the PosgreSQL repositories:

```
FROM ruby:3.2.2-bookworm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends postgresql-client-15
```